# Knots isotopic to their mirror image

Tags: knot-theory

How do you prove a knot is achiral?
Do you just show swap the under crossings and the over crossings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it suffices to give a sequence of [Reidemeister moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move) to transform the knot into its mirror image.  Proving that a knot is *chiral* is much more difficult.

Comment: why would someone give a sequence of Reidemeister moves if is much easier to just swap the crossings?

Comment: Suppose you have a knot $K$ and you swap the over and undercrossings to obtain $K'$.  Now you need to show that $K$ and $K'$ are the same.  How do you propose to do that?

Comment: oh fair enough. I really struggle with showing two knots are isotopic because I do not know what order to do the reidemeister moves, is there any short cut or do you any helpful tip? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I think no effective algorithm is known for finding the Reidemeister moves even when they exist. I think the problem is that one may in general need to introduce additional crossings that were not present before.

Comment: Hey I just have a question. In knot theory, is the process of smoothing just eliminating all the crossings?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Achiral knots must have self-conjugate HOMFLY polynomial. This does not prove that a knot is achiral, though, but it is a good criterion to test for chirality. Unfortunately it is not a complete invariant - there are also other knots having self-conjugate polynomial.
For a program in Mathematica finding the Reidemeister moves (in some easier cases), to show achirality, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AmphichiralKnot.html).